# Z-Order маркеров при кластеризации

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, cluster

Есть такой код (по непонятным причинам сниппет его не запускает)

```js
function initMap() {
  const point = {lat: 49.985, lng: 36.23};
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: point
  });
  
  const markers = [];
  const points = [point, point, point];
  for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: points[i]
    });
    markers.push(marker);
  };
  
  const markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/raw/gh-pages/images/m'
  });

  const res = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
      fillColor: "green",
      fillOpacity: 1,
      scale: 7,
      strokeWeight: 1,
    },
    zIndex: 100
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/raw/gh-pages/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

В нем в одну точку выводится три маркера, причем первые два кластеризируются при помощи библиотеки [js-marker-clusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer).

Проблема: я хочу некластеризированный маркер вывести поверх кластера. Для этого указываю ему `zIndex: 100`. Но он все равно выводит под кластером. Как его поднять наверх?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Если кто-то знает как заставить работать сниппет - подредактируйте сообщение

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50280280/5376639

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6894548/5376639

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10243855/5376639

Answer (score 0):

Как подсказали на enSO, проблема кроется в том, что объекты выводятся в разные слои.

На карте, по умолчанию, присутствуют [пять слоев](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapPanes)

1. `mapPane` — вывод тайлов карты
2. `overlayLayer` — отображение ломаных, полигонов, каких либо дополнительных тайлов поверхности
3. `markerLayer` — отображение маркеров
4. `overlayMouseTarget` — слой, который получает события DOM
5. `floatPane` — отображение всяких информационных окон

Все слои располагаются друг над другом. маркера выводятся на 3 слой, а кластеры на четвертый. Поэтому они всегда будут располагаться над маркерами.

Решение проблемы - создать свой слой, который будет выше чем `overlayMouseTarget` и добавлять маркеры в него

> <sub>Как разберусь, как добавлять маркеры на новый слой — дополню ответ</sub>